# Evento javascript solo se ejecuta para la primera fila

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo una tabla en html-bootstrap y, al final, un script javascript con un método AJAX que envía datos a un script php. Uso el evento *change* del *input* fecha en una ventana modal para obtener horarios disponibles y llenar un *select* con los registros obtenidos.

El problema es que el script solo se ejecuta para la primera fila de la tabla, para las demás ya no me responde, ¿a que se puede deber esto?

Este es mi javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    
    var horarios = $('#horarios');

    $('#fechacit').change(function(){
            var fecha_selecc = $(this).val();   

        if(fecha_selecc !== ''){        
                $.ajax({
                  data: {fecha_selecc:fecha_selecc}, 
                  dataType: 'html',                     
                  type: 'POST',                         
                  url: 'procesos_php/get_fechacita.php' 
                
                }).done(function(data){         

                horarios.html(data); 
                horarios.prop('disabled', false); 
            });

     }else{                                         
       horarios.val('');                
       horarios.prop('disabled', true); 
     }    
   });
 });
```

Este es el script php que devuelve valores a la solicitud ajax del javascript

```
<?php 

require("../bbdd/conexion_db.php");
try {

    if (isset($_POST['fecha_selecc'])) { 

        /*Obtenemos los horarios dsisponibles apara la fecha seleccionada */
        $sql = "SELECT id_horario, horario";
        $sql = $sql . " FROM horarios AS A";
        $sql = $sql . " WHERE (NOT EXISTS";
            $sql = $sql . " (SELECT id_hora";
            $sql = $sql . " FROM citas AS B";
            $sql = $sql . " WHERE A.id_horario = B.id_hora";
            $sql = $sql . " AND B.fecha_cita = :la_fech))";
            $sql = $sql . " ORDER BY A.id_horario";

        $rs = $cnnconex->prepare($sql);
        $rs->execute(array(":la_fech"=>$_POST['fecha_selecc']));

        $num_reg = $rs->rowCount();

        // <!-- código `html`, que sera retornado a `ajax` para llenar el combo horarios -->
        if ($num_reg!=0) { ?>
            <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
            <?php 
            while($reg = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $reg['id_horario']; ?>" ><?php echo $reg['horario']; ?></option>
            <?php 
            }

        }else{ ?>       <!-- sin horarios disponibles -->
            <option value="">- Sin Horarios -</option>
            <?php 
        }
    }else{
        echo "Error al procesar la Fecha seleccionada";
    }

} catch (Exception $e) {
    die("Error : " . $e->Getmessage());
    echo "Linea " . $e->getLine();

}
$rs->closecursor();
$cnnconex = null;

?>
```

Comment: Estás repitiendo ID de los elementos en cada fila, jQuery encuentra el primero y es el único donde aplica el evento porque los ID deben ser únicos.

Comment: Cuando necesitas asignar el mismo `id` a varios elementos, lo que debes hacer es asignar una `class` a esos elementos. Como te explicó Triby, buscando por ID solo encontrarás el primero ya que se supone que son únicos.

Comment: Quiero agradecerles por sus comentarios, en efecto debía acceder a través de la clase y no del id, nuevamente muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo de ayudarme